How to simplify and expression subjected to constraints?
It is possible to simplify the following expression
  A1^4 - 2*A2*x^2*y^2 + A3*x^4 + 2*I*z*(x - y)*(x + y)*(A2*x + I*A4*y) + 
  Sqrt[2]*z^(3/2)*(x - y)*(x + y) + Sqrt[2]*z^(5/2)*
   ((A1 + A2)*x^2 + 2*I*(A3 + A4)*x*y + (A1 + A4)*y^2) - 
  2*z^2*(2*I*(A2 + A5)*x*y + A1*(x^2 + y^2) - A6*(x^2 + y^2))

subjected to the condition that $x-y \ll z$ for some given constants $A1-A6$?

Depends on how you're interpreting $x-y$ being small. Here are two possibilities, based on the same idea.  The first is the interpretation that I  prefer when doing these kinds of things.
expr = A1^4 - 2*A2*x^2*y^2 + A3*x^4 + 2*I*z*(x - y)*(x + y)*(A2*x + I*A4*y) + Sqrt[2]*z^(3/2)*(x - y)*(x + y) + Sqrt[2]*z^(5/2)*((A1 + A2)*x^2 + 2*I*(A3 + A4)*x*y + (A1 + A4)*y^2) - 2*z^2*(2*I*(A2 + A5)*x*y + A1*(x^2 + y^2) - A6*(x^2 + y^2));

Replace $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\mathrm{diff} = x-y$ and $\mathrm{sum} = x+y$ via
expr2 = expr /. First@Solve[{x - y == diff, x + y == sum}, {x, y}];

Then, since $\mathrm{diff}=x-y$ is supposed to be small compared to $z$, replace $\mathrm{diff} = \frac{\mathrm{diff}}{z}z = \mathrm{diff}'z$:
expr3 = expr2 /. diff -> diffOverZ z;

Expand the expression in a power series in diffOverZ about diffOverZ==0 (keep as many terms as you think you want):
expr4 = Series[expr3, {diffOverZ, 0, 1}];

Normal out the higher-order terms and make the inverse replacements in terms of $x$ and $y$:
expr5 = Normal@expr4 /. {diffOverZ -> (x - y)/z, sum -> x + y};

Do whatever simplifications you need to do.

The other interpretation is to ignore the $x$'s and $y$'s that don't involve $x-y$ explicitly in your expression.  Do
Normal@Series[expr /. x - y -> diffOverZ z, {diffOverZ, 0, 1}] /. {diffOverZ -> (x - y)/z}

I trust the first method more, but again, it depends on how you're taking this asymptotic limit.
